# Cannot find local files placed in Airflow - GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator

Tags: airflow

We are using [GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator/google/transfer/gcs_to_local.html):

```
download_file = GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator(
    task_id='download_file',
    object_name='file_in_gcs.json',
    bucket='our-bucket',
    filename='local_file.json'
)
```

This task runs fine, however for our next task, which needs to import `local_file.json` to another database, I cannot find this file. In particular we're using `mongoimport` to import into mongodb, via `mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://user:pass@mydb.mongodb.net/dbname" --collection name_in_mongo --drop --file local_file.json` (called in a BashOperator), and we're receiving an error that `local_file.json` cannot be found.

How can we check to see where `local_file.json` is saved to?

Answer (score 1):

Using relative filenames, files will usually be stored in Airflow home folder.

You can infer this in Airflow configuration file (`airflow.cfg`) either in the terminal or through the Admin Dashboard. It's often a common prefix for the `dags_folder` and `base_log_folder`, except configured otherwise.

If you're running Airflow as a container based off `puckel/docker-airflow` image, the value of `AIRFLOW_HOME` is `/usr/local/airflow`. Otherwise you can easily rig up an operator to print that for you.

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.settings import AIRFLOW_HOME
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='where_is_home',
    start_date=datetime.now()
)

def command():

    print("$AIRFLOW_HOME=", AIRFLOW_HOME)

with dag:
    po = PythonOperator(
        task_id='print',
        python_callable=command,
        provide_context=True
    )
```

Most operators define tasks to be executed in `AIRFLOW_HOME`, save a few such as `PythonVirtualenvOperator` and `BashOperator` that execute inside a temporary folder. For your task (GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator) it's easily the `AIRFLOW_HOME`.

As `BashOperator` is [executing `command` in a temporary directory](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/bash.py#L149), you have to pass the absolute path to the downloaded file and not a relative one.

The path should be `f'{get_airflow_home()}/{local_file.json}`

```py
from airflow.settings import AIRFLOW_HOME
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

#...

command = ' '.join([
    'mongoimport',
    '--uri', 
    "mongodb+srv://user:pass@mydb.mongodb.net/dbname", 
    '--collection',
    'name_in_mongo', 
    '--drop', 
    '--file', 
    '$file_location',
])

bo = BashOperator(
    task_id="load_collection",
    command=command,
    env={'file_location': f'{AIRFLOW_HOME}/local_file.json'}
)
```